# How to change the pch in plot in categorically marked point pattern using spatstat in R

Tags: r, plot, spatstat, r-ppp

I have the data here [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1grMCx_T-EbPqe-cHPlcIjM37eGqd2tZt/view?usp=share_link). I want to plot the categorically marked point pattern using spatstat in R. I have tried doing this

```
x = c(3,0.5,1,0,0,0,2,2.5,5.5, 16,21,26,28,40, 47, 52, 58, 60, 65, 63, 63, 75, 77, 78, 75)
y = c(116,106,82.5,64,40,35,25,17.5,5,5,5,8,10,8, 14, 14, 10, 0, 0, 17, 20, 24, 30, 50, 116)
p <- owin(poly = cbind(x, y))
point_pattern = as.ppp(deviation_binary_category_locations_marks, p)
marks(point_pattern) <- deviation_binary_category_locations_marks[, "RPL32"]
ccc <- c("green","black")[marks(point_pattern)]
shapes = c(1,21)[marks(point_pattern)]
plot(point_pattern,which.marks="RPL32", main="Point pattern for gene RPL32")
plot(point_pattern,which.marks="RPL32",bg=ccc,pch = shapes, add=TRUE)
```

It results in a plot like this
[image: plot]

However, the circle and the triangle are not clear without colouring I think. How can I colour the triangle so it will be more obvious to see? Or change the triangle to a coloured circle? I have tried using the code mentioned above but nothing has change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use argument `cols` to specify colours for the different types of points, and `chars` to specify the plotting symbols for the different types of points. You could also use `cex` to control the size of the plot symbols to make them more distinct.

For further information see the help file for `plot.ppp`.

Comment: Thanks. I just found out about plot.ppp last night actually. This is what I have been looking for. I solve it using `plot(point_pattern,which.marks="FN1", main="Point pattern for gene FN1", chars = c("o","o"), bg = c("white", "green"),pch = 21, size = 0.75, cols = c("black", "green"))`